# Entity Framework performance over application lifetime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF 6.0 as an interface for my SQL Server database, and have been running into a re-occurring issue that I can't find a solution for other than setting up a auto-restart for the program.

I have a loop that will create a new `DbContext` and perform operations accordingly. After this loop goes for a few cycles the database operations will slow down to a crawl taking these iterations minutes to process when upon first launch it takes seconds.

I have tried things like disabling automatic change tracking and manual control of the garbage collection.

Here is what I am doing

```
while(true)
{
    var ctx = new DBContext();
    // ... Do operations
    sleep(10000);
}
```

I've tried searching for an answer to this problem for awhile but have been unable to find one

Comment: your code never disposes the context. Is that true for your real code?

Comment: to dispose use `using` eg. `using (var ctx = new DBContext()) { your code }` | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: Adding a using or manually disposing the context doesn't help also it is not necessary according to the documentation.

Comment: I suspect that there's a memory leak in the "operations". Is there anything in there that has a longer lifespan than the context?

Comment: Are you sure that you wanna create a new context in each loop iteration?? also it's and endless loop.

Comment: You need more detail in your question about the exact operations you are doing in a loop iteration. Firstly, disposing of the DbContext is 100% absolutely necessary, I'd be very interested to see what documentation said otherwise. Secondly, a very important detail would be what is living beyond a loop iteration such as storing references to entities loaded, etc. Without seeing what's really there I doubt anyone will be able to point out exactly what you are doing that would be causing the issue.